# How to get a list of soft deleted resources and vault entries in azure with managed c# code?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sdk-.net

I want to build an azure function app which collects the following data:

- soft deleted resources
- soft deleted Azure Key Vault entries

The goal is to have the entry point at subscription level. The function is supposed to query the subscription's resource groups to then search for things as specified above.

My researches shown that as of today (2022-06-29) the `Microsoft.Azure.Resources` packages are pretty much obsolete and the replacement packages `Azure.ResourceManager` are in kind of a preview state. I'm trying since yesterday to somehow get this data - but without much success because I do not really know how to get to the data.

At the moment my .csproj looks like this:

```xml
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Monitor.Query" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.ResourceManager" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.ResourceManager.KeyVault" Version="1.0.0-beta.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.ResourceManager.Monitor" Version="1.0.0-beta.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.ResourceManager.Resources" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.ResourceManager.Compute" Version="1.0.0-beta.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.ResourceManager.Network" Version="1.0.0-beta.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.ResourceManager.Storage" Version="1.0.0-beta.8" />
```

And my function class is also pretty messy, because I do not really know where to start here. So I tried to install a bunch of packages to eventually get an extension method with something useful >.<

```cs
using System;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.ResourceManager;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Resources;
using Azure.ResourceManager.ManagementGroups;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Models;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Storage;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Compute;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Network;
using Azure.ResourceManager.KeyVault;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Monitor;

using Azure.Monitor.Query;

using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SoftDeleteDetection.Models;

//using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Models;
//using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models;

namespace SoftDeleteDetection;

public class NotifyOnSoftDeletedResourcesFunctions
{
    [FunctionName("ScanAndNotify")]
    public async Task ScanAndNotify([TimerTrigger("0 0 9 * * MON")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

        await DoSomething();
    }

    private async Task DoSomething()
    {


        //var credentials = new EnvironmentCredential();
        var credentials = new VisualStudioCredential();

        ArmClient client = new(credentials, Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(Settings.SubscriptionId));

        var subscription = await client.GetDefaultSubscriptionAsync();

        var resourceGroups = subscription.GetResourceGroups();

        foreach (var group in resourceGroups)
        {
            var resources = group.GetGenericResources("");

            var vaults = group.GetVaults();

            foreach (var vault in vaults)
            {
                var secrets = vault.GetSecrets();

                foreach (var secret in secrets)
                {
                    // no useful property here
                }

                var keys = vault.GetVaultKeys();
                foreach (var key in keys)
                {
                    // no useful property here
                }
            }

            //var dada = group.Getkey

            //Azure.ResourceManager.KeyVault.


            //if (group.GetGenericResources())
            //var dudu = group.GetStorageAccounts();
        }


        ////var subscription = await armClient.GetDefaultSubscriptionAsync();
        ////subscription.

        //string rgName = "myResourceGroup";
        //SubscriptionResource subscription = await armClient.GetDefaultSubscriptionAsync();
        //var fufu = await subscription.GetResourceGroups().GetAsync("myRg");
        //fufu.Value.

        //ResourceGroup rg = await subscription.GetResourceGroups().GetAsync(rgName);
        //await foreach (VirtualMachine vm in rg.GetVirtualMachines().GetAllAsync())
        //{
        //    //previously we would have to take the resourceGroupName and the vmName from the vm object
        //    //and pass those into the powerOff method as well as we would need to execute that on a separate compute client
        //    await vm.StartPowerOff().WaitForCompletionAsync();
        //}

        //var rp = subscription.GetResourceProvider("Microsoft.ApiManagement");
        ////rp.Value.

        //var rgs = subscription.GetResourceGroups();

        ////ResourceGroup resourceGroup = await subscription.GetResourceGroups().GetAsync("myRgName");

        //foreach (var group in rgs) 
        //{
        //    //var det = group.getre.Get();
        //    //det.Value.GetVirtualMachines();
        //}

        //var mg = client.GetManagementGroups();
        //var mgs = mg.GetAll();
        //foreach (var item in mgs)
        //{
        //    //item.
        //    //item.
        //}

        //var sc = client.GetSubscriptions();
        //var subs = sc.GetAll();

        //foreach (var item in subs)
        //{
        //    //item.
        //}
    }
}

I would be very happy if someone can point me to the right direction.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> soft deleted resources

AFAIK, currently there is **no specific class libraries** or **CLI & PowerShell** commands to fetch the soft deleted resources

> soft deleted Azure Key Vault entries

We can retrieve the soft deleted Key Vault entries details by using **Portal, Azure CLI, PowerShell**. Refer the [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/key-vault-recovery?tabs=azure-powershell#what-are-soft-delete-and-purge-protection)

In C# you can use the **[DeletedSecretIdentifier.IsDeletedSecretIdentifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.keyvault.deletedsecretidentifier.isdeletedsecretidentifier?view=azure-dotnet-legacy#microsoft-azure-keyvault-deletedsecretidentifier-isdeletedsecretidentifier%28system-string%29)** to check whether the identifier belongs to a key vault deleted secret

[Get Deleted Secrect Identifier in key vault using .net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.keyvault.deletedsecretidentifier?view=azure-dotnet-legacy)

#### References

- [Soft-delete (Key Vault)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/soft-delete-overview)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I solved it a bit differently using Azure Montor. You'll then need to use `Azure.Identity` and `Azue.Monitor.Query`.

I fire off two queries. One against AzureActivity and one against AzureDiagnostics.

Comment: @jack do you have more information on the query you used? was it specific to key vault?